# use DKMS to install realtek r8125 driver, get No rule to make target 'CLEAN'

Tags: makefile, driver, linux-device-driver, gnu-make, dkms

I try to use dkms to install realtek r8125 driver.
The official driver autorun script use this to compile source code

```
make $@ all 1>>log.txt || exit 1
```

the top level makefile is

```
KFLAG := 2$(shell uname -r | sed -ne 's/^2\.[4]\..*/4/p')x

all: clean modules install

modules:
ifeq ($(KFLAG),24x)
    $(MAKE) -C src/ -f Makefile_linux24x modules
else
    $(MAKE) -C src/ modules
endif

clean:
ifeq ($(KFLAG),24x)
    $(MAKE) -C src/ -f Makefile_linux24x clean
else
    $(MAKE) -C src/ clean
endif

install:
ifeq ($(KFLAG),24x)
    $(MAKE) -C src/ -f Makefile_linux24x install
else
    $(MAKE) -C src/ install
endif
```

my dkms.conf is

```
PACKAGE_NAME="realtek-r8125"
PACKAGE_VERSION="9.009.01"
MAKE="'make' $@ all"
CLEAN="'make' clean"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="r8125"
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="src"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/kernel/driver/net/ethernet/realtek"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
REMAKE_INITRD=no
```

when I build this project, I get an error

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'CLEAN'.  Stop.
```

when I change dkms.conf like this

```
PACKAGE_NAME="realtek-r8125"
PACKAGE_VERSION="9.009.01"
MAKE="'make' all"
CLEAN="'make' clean"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="r8125"
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="src"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/kernel/driver/net/ethernet/realtek"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
REMAKE_INITRD=no
```

it run success

why DKMS say "No rule to make target 'CLEAN'" even if there is a clean target in makefile

what is the difference between `make all` and `make $@ all`

Comment: 1. the target `make` try to build is called `CLEAN`, and not `clean`. So, something has called `make CLEAN`, which doesn't exist. 2. `$@` is your shell positional parameters ($1 $2 ..) ; it seems useless in your context

Comment: Like virtually all POSIX tools, `make` is case-sensitive.